# Stripe Error "There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier."

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, next-auth

When trying to create "checkout_session" using Stripe Firebase Extension with Nextauth getting error " "There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier." After trying to push "checkout_sessions" to users collection to load the checkout page.
Here is the code Iam using.

```
  const loadCheckOut = async (priceId) => {

    const docRef = await 
    addDoc(collection(db, "users", 
   `${session.user.id}`,
        "checkout_sessions"), { 
        price: priceId,
        success_url: 
        window.location.origin,
        cancel_url: 
        window.location.origin,
      });
      console.log(docRef)

      onSnapshot(docRef, (snap) => {
         const { error, url } = 
          snap.data();
         console.log(error)
        if (error) {
        // Show an error to your customer 
           and
        // inspect your Cloud Function logs in the Firebase console.
        alert(`An error occured: ${error.message}`);
      }
      if (url) {
        // We have a Stripe Checkout URL, 
        let's redirect.
        window.location.assign(url);                                        
 })                   
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a few months since this question was initially asked, but I'll share anyway a possible solution because I recently ran into the same issue. So, if anyone else is having trouble using the *Stripe Firebase Extension* (now officially transferred to *Invertase*, aka `@invertase/firestore-stripe-payments`) along with *Next-Auth*, this might help you out.

Basically, the issue is with the *next-auth* authentication process. Meaning that, while the package creates/updates user data in the `users` and `accounts` Firebase collections/docs when users sign in/up, it sadly *doesn't* authenticate them also on the Firebase Authentication dashboard, i.e. this one (yours will probably be empty right now):

[image: Firebase Authentication dashboard example]

Hence, this is the main issue causing the `"There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier"` error to pop up.

So, to fix that, we are going to simply authenticate the user also on the *Firebase Authentication* dashboard. Now, here's how I organized my project files/code, yours might be different, but quite similar in the logics.

Simplified project file structure view:

```
/
├── app
|     ├── _components
|     |     ├── (auth)
|     |     |     └── NextAuthSessionProvider.jsx
|     |     └── // Other folders/files
|     ├── _lib
|     |     ├── firebase
|     |     |     ├── authentication.js
|     |     |     └── firestore-database.js
|     |     └── auth.js
|     ├── api
|     |     ├── auth
|     |     |     └── [...nextauth]
|     |     |                └── route.js
|     |     └── // Other API routes
|     └── // Other folders/files
└── // Other folders/files
```

`/app/_lib/firebase/authentication.js` (i.e. all operations regarding the `firebase-admin` package):

```js
import { initFirestore } from "@auth/firebase-adapter";
import { cert, getApps, initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase-admin/auth";

const firebaseAdminSettings = {
    credential: cert({
        projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_PROJECT_ID,
        clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_CLIENT_EMAIL,
        privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_ADMIN_PRIVATE_KEY,
    }),
};

export const firebaseAdmin =
    getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseAdminSettings) : getApps()[0];
export const firebaseAdminFirestore = initFirestore(firebaseAdminSettings);
export { getAuth };
```

`/app/_lib/auth.js` (i.e. *next-auth* config file):

```js
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { FirestoreAdapter } from "@auth/firebase-adapter";

// Here '@lib/firebase/authentication' refers to the '/app/_lib/firebase/authentication.js' file
import { firebaseAdminFirestore, getAuth } from "@lib/firebase/authentication";

export const authOptions = {
    providers: [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    adapter: FirestoreAdapter(firebaseAdminFirestore),
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    callbacks: {
        jwt: async ({ user, token }) => {
            if (user) {
                token.uid = user.id;

                const auth = getAuth();
                try {
                    await auth.getUser(token.uid);
                } catch (error) {
                    if (error.code === "auth/user-not-found") {
                        // If the user does not exist, create a new user
                        await auth.createUser({
                            uid: token.uid,
                            email: token.email,
                            displayName: token.name,
                            photoURL: token.picture,
                        });
                    } else {
                        throw error;
                    }
                }
            }
            return token;
        },
        session: async ({ session, token }) => {
            if (token && token.uid) {
                if (session?.user) {
                    session.user.id = token.uid;

                    const auth = getAuth();
                    const firebaseToken = await auth.createCustomToken(token.uid);
                    session.firebaseToken = firebaseToken;
                }
            }
            return session;
        },
    },
};
```

`/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js` (i.e. api endpoint for *next-auth*):

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";

// Here '@lib/auth' refers to the '/app/_lib/auth.js' file
import { authOptions } from "@lib/auth";

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

`/app/_components/(auth)/NextAuthSessionProvider.jsx` (i.e. *next-auth* session provider wrapper + listener to sync with *Firebase Authentication*):

```js
"use client";

import { useEffect } from "react";
import { SessionProvider, useSession } from "next-auth/react";

// Here '@lib/firebase/firestore-database' refers to the '/app/_lib/firebase/firestore-database.js' file
import { syncWithFirebaseAuth } from "@lib/firebase/firestore-database";

const SyncWithFirebaseAuth = () => {
    const { data: session } = useSession();

    useEffect(() => {
        syncWithFirebaseAuth(session);
    }, [session]);

    return null;
};

const NextAuthSessionProvider = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <SessionProvider>
            <SyncWithFirebaseAuth />
            {children}
        </SessionProvider>
    );
};

export default NextAuthSessionProvider;
```

`/app/_lib/firebase/firestore-database.js` (i.e. all operations regarding the Firestore database):

```js
import { initializeApp, getApps } from "firebase/app";
import {
    getFirestore,
    collection,
    addDoc,
    query,
    where,
    onSnapshot,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth, signInWithCustomToken } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

export const firebaseApp =
    getApps().length === 0 ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApps()[0];
export const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
export const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

export const syncWithFirebaseAuth = async (session) => {
    if (session && session.firebaseToken) {
        try {
            await signInWithCustomToken(auth, session.firebaseToken);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error signing in with custom token:", error);
        }
    } else {
        auth.signOut();
    }
};

/**
 * STRIPE UTILITIES
 */

export const createStripeCheckoutURL = async (userId, origin, locale) => {
    const docRef = await addDoc(
        collection(firestore, `users/${userId}/checkout_sessions`),
        {
            price: "...",
            locale,
            success_url: origin,
            cancel_url: origin,
        }
    );

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(docRef, (snap) => {
            const { error, url } = snap.data();

            if (error) {
                // Stop listening for changes
                unsubscribe();
                reject(new Error(`An error occurred: ${error.message}`));
            }
            if (url) {
                // Stop listening for changes
                unsubscribe();
                resolve(url);
            }
        });
    });
};

export const getStripeSubscriptionStatus = async (userId) => {
    const stripeSubscriptionsRef = collection(
        firestore,
        `users/${userId}/subscriptions`
    );
    const q = query(
        stripeSubscriptionsRef,
        where("status", "in", ["trialing", "active"])
    );

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
            q,
            (snapshot) => {
                if (snapshot.docs.length === 0) {
                    resolve(false);
                } else {
                    resolve(true);
                }
                unsubscribe();
            },
            reject
        );
    });
};

export const getStripePortalLink = async (userId, origin, locale) => {
    let portalLink;
    try {
        const functions = getFunctions(firebaseApp, "[your Firebase location, e.g. europe-west3]");
        const functionRef = httpsCallable(
            functions,
            "ext-firestore-stripe-payments-createPortalLink"
        );
        const { data } = await functionRef({
            returnUrl: origin,
            locale,
            customerId: userId,
        });

        portalLink = data?.url;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (portalLink) {
            resolve(portalLink);
        } else {
            reject(new Error("No Stripe portal link returned."));
        }
    });
};

// Other Firebase CRUD operations
```

---

I know it's a long answer, but I've tried to present you a working example. Now, here's a couple of observations:

- To authenticate the user also to the *Firebase Authentication dashboard*, I've used the Firebase `createCustomToken` and `signInWithCustomToken` utilities.
- I've also utilized the Firebase `createUser({ ... })` method just to make sure that each user inside the *Firebase Authentication dashboard* had a **non-empty identifier** (in this case, it will be equals to the user's email). ***This is an additional step***, but I've done it just to later have the user's email pre-filled in the Stripe checkout session form, like so:

  [image: pre-filled email field on the stripe checkout page]

  Thus, if you're not interested having this behavior, you can remove this part.
- At the time of writing - March 2024 - the `@invertase/firestore-stripe-payments` [SDK built-in methods](https://github.com/invertase/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/next/firestore-stripe-web-sdk/README.md), e.g. `getStripePayments`, `createCheckoutSession`, etc., are still not working properly (probably due to the fact that the lib uses an old version of Firebase), and that's why - as in the original question - you might have noticed that in the `/app/_lib/firebase/firestore-database.js` file I've created, based on the docs, some utilities to interact with the lib. **Hence keep an eye out for future package updates that resolve this inconvenience**.
- As in the previous point, perhaps in the future, there will be some updates to the `next-auth` package too that will integrate all of this additional Firebase authentication logic. So, keep an eye out for that too!
- Since I've used the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix on the *Firebase env variables*, keep also in mind to create adequate Firebase ***rules*** in order to protect the db.

---

Finally, just to provide you with the full context, this solution was tested - and worked fine - with these project package versions:

```
"@auth/firebase-adapter": "^1.4.0",
"@invertase/firestore-stripe-payments": "^0.0.7",
"firebase": "^10.8.0",
"firebase-admin": "^11.11.1",
"next": "^14.0.4"
"next-auth": "^4.24.6",
```